# responsive breakpoints not working for ngx-slick on angular 7

Tags: angular, responsive-design, slick.js

I have added ngx-slick component to my angular 7 app but the reponsive breakpoints not working. when ever breakpoint is reached (for mobile view) nothing is displayed.

```
HTML - 

<ngx-slick class="carousel" id="slider" #slickModal="slick-modal" [config]="slideConfig" 
     (afterChange)="afterChange($event)" (breakpoint)="breakpoint($event)">
         <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide bg-light ">         
             <img src="{{'assets/img/features/'+ slide.img }}" alt="" width="80%"class="slide-image">
             <h6 class="slide-title">{{slide.title}}</h6>              
         </div>
     </ngx-slick>
```

slide Configurations-

```
 slideConfig = {'slidesToShow': 4, 'slidesToScroll': 4,
  'autoplay': true, 'autoplaySpeed': 3500, 'infinite': true,
  'mobileFirst': false,'respondTo': 'window',
  'rows': 1, 
  'responsive': [{
    'breakpoint': 600,
    'settings': {    
        'slidesToShow': 1,
        'slidesToScroll': 1,
        'arrows': true,
        'dots': true
      }
    }]
};
```

Already searched a lot nothing worked even tried switching mobileFirst but no luck.plz help I am stuck.

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: NO i switched to woo flexslider